# Passing Params to a page in key-value pair in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, get, parameters, getparameter

I am using CodeIgniter, and I am new to it.
I came to know that I can pass parameters to another page like http://example.com/users/list/param1/param2/param3/.... and so on.

Now on the destination php script, I can get it as $this->uri->segment(2) , but I must know that which location it is in the uri. Say I am getting param2 , I must know that it is uri segment 4. This is a great pain for me. I previously worked with ZEND , where we send parameters like 
http://examples.com/controller/action/key/value/key/value , Now in this case I can always dynamic number of parameters and I don't need to know their location in the uri, but I just need to know the key.

Qestion : Is there a way where I can pass parameters using GET in key-value pairs in codeigniter, like the one ZEND do?

Comment: I got the answer, here it is 
 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html look for

               $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the function `$this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n)` in the `URI` class. It will take in your url segments as an associative array. You could then check whether the keys are present in it or not.

Example and full explanation [in the user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html).

Comment: That was pretty much my answer word for word

Comment: Thanx Anzeo, It was really stupid of me that why I didn't search user guide for this, :) . Thank you.

Comment: @Sohail, you're welcome. And don't worry, your question might help others who don't know about the user guide ;)